# Facted navigation using checkbox

Tags: java, spring-mvc, liferay

I want a page in which list is need to be displayed and further I need to refine the result of list based on checked checkbox. i have set of checkboxes like filter by date , filter by status etc. In each set of checkbox, multiple options can be selected.

what i have tried till now is that i m retrieving separate list for each checkbox selected in the controller class. can u tell me how can i merge all the list in single based on selection (I also don't want duplicate entries) and pass it to my view.jsp or any other way to do this.

and one more thing when m using onClick for radio or checkox html input tag, action is triggered but tick is not getting retained in view page. Option is getting unchecked automatically on page refresh